# JavaScript / NodeJS gives an error doing the replace function. in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot, but this error keeps happening. what is the problem?
I have made it so it will log everything:

```
else if(message.content.startsWith("$t inform ")){
        var target = message.content.replace("$t inform ", "").split(",");
        var i = 0;
        var tosend = fs.readFileSync("msginform.txt", 'utf-8');
        while(i < target.length){
            console.log(target);
            console.log(target.length);
            if(i < target.length)console.log("was bigger");
            console.log("type of i: "+(typeof i));
            console.log("i: "+i);
            console.log("target 0:"+target[0]);
            console.log("target 1:"+target[1]);
            console.log("target i:"+target[i]);
            console.log("attempt to send to: "+target[i].replace("<@","").replace(">",""));
            client.users.fetch(target[i].replace("<@","").replace(">",""), false).then((user) => {
            user.send(tosend);
            console.log("[inform] message sent: "+target[i].replace("<@","").replace(">",""))
            });
            i++;
        }
    }
```

what the terminal output's:

```
WAIT FOR THE BOT TO START.......
Discord = discord.js
Client and Intents = discord.js
request library setup
fs library setup
client login setup
read config.json
decode config.json
extract token and perfix from config.json
extract limited list from limit.json
login....
ONLINE AT 2022-12-20 14:6:37
[ '<@745157949122543686>', '<@780133749669101659>' ]
2
was bigger
type of i: number
i: 0
target 0:<@745157949122543686>
target 1:<@780133749669101659>
target i:<@745157949122543686>
attempt to send to: 745157949122543686
[ '<@745157949122543686>', '<@780133749669101659>' ]
2
was bigger
type of i: number
i: 1
target 0:<@745157949122543686>
target 1:<@780133749669101659>
target i:<@780133749669101659>
attempt to send to: 780133749669101659
C:\Users\kamya\OneDrive\Desktop\Media\tkpixel-js-bot-2-6-2022-BACKUP-LAST\index.js:234
            console.log("[inform] message sent: "+target[i].replace("<@","").replace(">",""))
                                                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
    at C:\Users\kamya\OneDrive\Desktop\Media\tkpixel-js-bot-2-6-2022-BACKUP-LAST\index.js:234:61
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

I expect it to work fine and send a message (from the msginform.txt file) to 2 people

Comment: The error message is pretty clear `Cannot read properties of undefined`. `target[i]` is `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.
so the problem was that I didn't know that the replace function was actually changing the variable target[i]. so by trying to log it, I was actually causing the problem